# Problem with mount volumes of Docker File

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I installed docker CE and docker compose on a new installation of Ubuntu (18.10). Since, I have a bug with volumes mount with docker-compose. I precise the docker-compose I'm using was the same than with my previous laptop (which run on Ubuntu 16.04). Volumes mount from my home directory are all empty and permissions aren't good.

```
version: '3.3'

# We define volumes here.
# In this case, we define a volume for the database but it's overkill
# because we used this volume only with one container.
volumes:
  db-volume:

# We define containers here
services:

  # DB container
  db:
    # We use the image of mariadb (https://hub.docker.com/_/mariadb/).
    # Like we don't precise tag, it's the latest version image which is           download.
    image: mariadb
    # We define environment variable like explained in the documentation of the image.
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root_password
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=${DATABASE_NAME}
      - MYSQL_USER=drupal
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=drupal
    # We used the volume previously defined.
    volumes:
      - db-volume:/var/lib/mysql

    php-cli:
    # Here, we use a Dockerfile and not a Docker Image. The file is Dockerfile-php-cli and is in the same repository
    # than the docker-compose.yml
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile-php-cli
      # Arguments pass to the Dockerfile.
      args:
        USER_UID: ${USER_UID}
    volumes:
      # Data of application
      - ./:/var/www/html:rw
      # Share the local user's npm cache as a Docker volume
      - ~/.npm:/home/php/.npm:rw
      # Share the local user's SSH keys and configuration (read-only)
      - ~/.ssh:/home/php/.ssh:ro
      # Share the local user's known_host
      - ~/.ssh/known_hosts:/home/php/.ssh/known_hosts:rw
      # Share the local user's gitconfig
      - ~/.gitconfig:/home/php/.gitconfig
    environment:
      # We define the PATH and add the bin directory of vendor.
      - PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/var/www/html/vendor/bin
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=${DATABASE_NAME}
      - MYSQL_USER=drupal
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=drupal
    links:
      - db
```

I try to change my docker-compose to use the long syntax and I have this bug:

> Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:348: starting container process caused "process_linux.go:402: container init caused \"rootfs_linux.go:58: mounting \\"/home/desbois/snap/docker/321/.ssh/known_hosts\\" to rootfs \\"/var/snap/docker/common/var-lib-docker/aufs/mnt/bfbdb2e84826cc2526e5d8220847465065188cd57cb2e86aec700303b0f8bf9e\\" at \\"/var/snap/docker/common/var-lib-docker/aufs/mnt/bfbdb2e84826cc2526e5d8220847465065188cd57cb2e86aec700303b0f8bf9e/home/php/.ssh/known_hosts\\" caused \\"not a directory\\"\"": unknown: Are you trying to mount a directory onto a file (or vice-versa)? Check if the specified host path exists and is the expected type

And indeed, the file .ssh/known_hosts is a directory on the container php-cli.

I don't understand what's happened.

Comment: Looks like you are trying to mount a file rather than a folder; ~/.gitconfig:/home/php/.gitconfig

Comment: Can you check if all the mounted directories/file exist? Especially the known_hosts file?

Comment: It seems that the directory ~/.ssh have mounted in the container and the ~/.ssh/know_hosts just in the directory. Try to delete the mount `~/.ssh/known_hosts:/home/php/.ssh/known_hosts:rw` and just use it.

Comment: I remove all mount except html and .ssh in the docker-compose file. I delete the container and the image and rebuild php-cli. A directory known_hosts still exists in the directory .ssh on my container. But on my machine, it's a file. Additionally, my files id_rsa and id_rsa.pub don't exist.

Comment: If I copy my directory .ssh to put it in my project and mount it like `./copy_ssh:/home/php/.ssh:rw`, it works correctly. I think the version of docker or docker-compose I'm using have change the behavior when we mount directories from a user home or something like that.